# How do I simplify this javascript snippet into something more useful

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have created the following...code to test drag and drop of 10 objects, but I need help to create any number of drag and droppable objects...I'm looking for a way to dynamically create each drag and droppable object and to capture the coords for each at all times....

```
var oA = document.all ? document.all["a"] : document.getElementById("a")
        var oB = document.all ? document.all["b"] : document.getElementById("b")
        var oC = document.all ? document.all["c"] : document.getElementById("c")
        var oD = document.all ? document.all["d"] : document.getElementById("d")
        var oE = document.all ? document.all["e"] : document.getElementById("e")
        var oF = document.all ? document.all["f"] : document.getElementById("f")
        var oG = document.all ? document.all["g"] : document.getElementById("g")
        var oH = document.all ? document.all["h"] : document.getElementById("h")
        var oI = document.all ? document.all["i"] : document.getElementById("i")
        var oJ = document.all ? document.all["j"] : document.getElementById("j")

        var fA = document.all ? document.all["fA"] : document.getElementById("fA")
        var fB = document.all ? document.all["fB"] : document.getElementById("fB")
        var fC = document.all ? document.all["fC"] : document.getElementById("fC")
        var fD = document.all ? document.all["fD"] : document.getElementById("fD")
        var fE = document.all ? document.all["fE"] : document.getElementById("fE")
        var fF = document.all ? document.all["fF"] : document.getElementById("fF")
        var fG = document.all ? document.all["fG"] : document.getElementById("fG")
        var fH = document.all ? document.all["fH"] : document.getElementById("fH")
        var fI = document.all ? document.all["fI"] : document.getElementById("fI")
        var fJ = document.all ? document.all["fJ"] : document.getElementById("fJ")

        Drag.init(oA, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oB, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oC, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oD, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oE, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oF, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oG, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oH, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oI, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        Drag.init(oJ, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);

        oA.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fA, fA1, "A", x, y); }
        oB.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fB, fB1, "B", x, y); }
        oC.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fC, fC1, "C", x, y); }
        oD.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fD, fD1, "D", x, y); }
        oE.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fE, fE1, "E", x, y); }
        oF.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fF, fF1, "F", x, y); }
        oG.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fG, fG1, "G", x, y); }
        oH.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fH, fH1, "H", x, y); }
        oI.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fI, fI1, "I", x, y); }
        oJ.onDragEnd = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fJ, fJ1, "J", x, y); }

        oA.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fA, fA1, "A", x, y); }
        oB.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fB, fB1, "B", x, y); }
        oC.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fC, fC1, "C", x, y); }
        oD.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fD, fD1, "D", x, y); }
        oE.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fE, fE1, "E", x, y); }
        oF.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fF, fF1, "F", x, y); }
        oG.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fG, fG1, "G", x, y); }
        oH.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fH, fH1, "H", x, y); }
        oI.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fI, fI1, "I", x, y); }
        oJ.onDrag = function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(fJ, fJ1, "J", x, y); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, and using three arrays to hold strings you've used, it could be refactored like this:

```
var arr1=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
var arr2=["fA","fB","fC","fD","fE","fF","fG","fH","fI","fJ"];
var arr3=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];
var numobjects=10;

for(i=0 to numobjects-1)
{
    var o[i]=document.all?document.all[arr1[i]]:document.getElementById(arr1[i]);
    var f[i]=document.all?document.all[arr2[i]]:document.getElementById(arr2[i]);
    Drag.init(o[i], null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
    o[i].onDragEnd=function(x, y) {keepDragEnd(f[i], f1[i], arr3[i], x, y);}
    oA.onDrag=function(x, y) {keepDragEnd(f[i], f1[i], arr3[i], x, y);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth. This only solve part of the problem. For instance, what's needed if there's say only 2 items to drag around and the next time 25 items. The variable arr1, 2, 3 etc are still static as you've declared them...or am I missing something?

Comment: The first and second array store the ids of the elements in the page - unless you generate those with some particular formula (are they always going to be letters of the alphabet in sequence? What happens if there are more than 26 items? etc.) then you need to put each id into an array so the code knows what to look for. The other alternative is to generate those elements dynamically. As for the third array - I've no idea what the "A","B","C" etc. relate to, so I had to copy them verbatim into an array. If you want a more detailed answer you need a more detailed question I'm afraid.

Comment: The letters are in sequence. I've removed the 3rd array...it's no longer needed. 

The problem is the drag and drop function doesn't work when there are less objects initially placed on the page than declared...for example the server code writes say 2 IMG's to the page...however the javascript initiates 10...and the drag and drop no longer works.

Comment: @orovis You can just change the value of `numobjects` to match the number of objects you need. If you need more than 10 you'll also need to add more items to the static arrays to match. You could write a line of code before the loop to count how many such objects have been placed on the page and use that to initialize the `numobjects` variable.

Comment: Tried that...checked numobjects matches the actual objects placed on the page...but drag and drop only seems to work if the original script is there..I'm using dom_drag.js as the core d&d script.

Comment: Are you getting a Javascript error in Firebug/Chrome developer tools?

Comment: Using Safari..nothing related to dom-drag or the posted code or your script

Comment: ...
var numobjects=<%=iRecordsShown%>;

for(i=0 to numobjects-1) {
    var o[i]=document.all?document.all[arr1[i]]:document.getElementById(arr1[i]);
    var f[i]=document.all?document.all[arr2[i]]:document.getElementById(arr2[i]);
    var f1[i]=document.all?document.all[arr3[i]]:document.getElementById(arr3[i]);
    Drag.init(o[i], null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
    o[i].onDragEnd=function(x, y) {keepDragEnd(f[i], f1[i], x, y);}
    o[i].onDrag=function(x, y) {keepDragEnd(f[i], f1[i], x, y);}
}
....

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr_id = [/* the ids */];
var arr_id_f = [/* the ids */];
var len = "{$ servers output here }";/* elem numbers you want set */
function init (  ) {
    var oa;
    function getOnDrag ( a, b ) {
        return function(x, y) { keepDragEnd(a, b, "A", x, y); }
    }       
    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i += 1 ){
        Drag.init(oa, null, 0, 278, 0, 278);
        oa = document.getElementById( arr_id[i] );
        oA.onDrag = oa.onDragEnd = getOnDrag ( document.getElementById( arr_id_f[i] ), /* you dont mention what should be here */oa1 );
    }
}
init()
```

you could insert the code on a jsp page and output the len; on server side, js just strings

in my opinion,you may set the elems a same classname, so get them by  `getElementsByClassName` or use jquery or whatever you like, it will be more reusable